# Link Image CSS won't center Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, center

The link images refuses to center in the product box. I have tried adding text-align: center and display: block and margin: 0 auto to  but it won't center! For some strange reason, the description class works but the center class does not!

Could someone clue me into what's wrong?

HTML:

```
1 <div id="container_product_photos">
2 
3 
4 <% @product_photos.each do |photo| %>
5   <div class="product_box" >
6     <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image.url(:small)), product_photo_path(photo), class: 'center' %>
7     <p class='description'><%= photo.name %> </p>
8   </div> 
9 <% end %>
10     
11 </div>
```

Partial CSS file:

```
5 #container_product_photos{
6   margin: 0 auto; 
7   width: 650px;
8   overflow:hidden;
9   .product_box { 
10     height: 200px;
11     width: 180px;
12     float:left;
13     
14     .center {
15       margin: 0 auto;
16 
17     }
18     
19     .description {
20         width: 70px;
21         margin: 0 auto; 
22      }
23   }
24 }
```

Comment: Your css is malformed, You cant nest selectors.

Comment: @Musa, maybe it's less or scss ?? http://lesscss.org/ http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: +1 for the info, from the examples on the site LESS actually looks like **more**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .center class wouldn't do anything with `margin:0 auto` set b/c the HTML link tag (`<a></a>`) is not a block element. You could do this:

```
.center {
    display:block;
    width:???px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Replace ??? with the width of your image.